# Cross join in Data.table doesnt seem to retain column names

Tags: r, data.table, cross-join

`data.table` documentation says this, see `?CJ`:

> x = c(1,1,2)
>
> y = c(4,6,4)
>
> CJ(x, y) # output columns are automatically named 'x' and 'y'

However when I run the example, it doesnt seem to be retained

```
x = c(1,1,2)
y = c(4,6,4)
CJ(x, y)
   V1 V2
1:  1  4
2:  1  4
3:  1  4
4:  1  4
5:  1  6
6:  1  6
7:  2  4
8:  2  4
9:  2  6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That names are retained is not mentioned in the main body of the help file `?CJ`, that is in the Details or Value section. However, there appears to be mention that names are retained as a comment in the examples section of the help file (and it looks like this is where you got your example).

Digging around in the `CJ` function, which appears to be entirely implemented in R, there is a block near the end,

```
if (getOption("datatable.CJ.names", FALSE))
    vnames = name_dots(...)$vnames
```

Running `getOption("datatable.CJ.names", FALSE)` returns FALSE with `data.table` version 1.12.0. When we set this to TRUE with

```
options("datatable.CJ.names"=TRUE)
```

then the code

```
x = c(1,1,2)
y = c(4,6,4)

CJ(x, y)
```

returns

```
   x y
1: 1 4
2: 1 4
3: 1 4
4: 1 4
5: 1 6
6: 1 6
7: 2 4
8: 2 4
9: 2 6
```

However, you are also able to directly provide names (which is not mentioned in the help file).

```
CJ(uu=x, vv=y)
```

which returns

```
   uu vv
1:  1  4
2:  1  4
3:  1  4
4:  1  4
5:  1  6
6:  1  6
7:  2  4
8:  2  4
9:  2  6
```

Note that this overrides the above option.

Comment: What is odd is that this issue was seemingly addressed at some point, no?https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/a0fd4639e12cbe153bd98b036baf5aabfec4af2a  

Regardless, an issue with the documentation should probably raised.

Comment: @Peter_Evan That is interesting. That change was made on January 19, while it looks like version 1.12.0 was released on January 13. The change is mentioned as the third item in the [News page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md) for 1.12.1.